# c# api button click

Tags: c#, api

With 'Calculator', I can click button by use FindWindowEx and SendMessage.
But some application can't use spy++ to get information of button. 
For example 'Visual Studio'. How I can click buttons in this application?

Comment: Show your code and efforts and describe your problem in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Forms or Win32, UI elements like buttons are native OS window objects. However, I believe Visual Studio is written using WPF where buttons are not native OS window objects, so FindWindowEx will not work on them. You should try to using [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to interact with user interfaces (e.g. to [click buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747211%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and tools like [Inspect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).